# How do I use collections in MongoDB and sails.js?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

## Problem:

I want to get an attribute from one model which is nested in another.

## My solution:

I have two models in my application, one is users and the other is events:

user:

```
attributes: {
    name: 'STRING',
    email: 'STRING',
    events: {
        collection: 'event',
        via: 'author'
    }
}
```

event:

```
attributes: {
    date: 'STRING',
    time: 'STRING',,
    other: 'STRING',
    author: {
        model: 'user'
    }
}
```

One user should be able to create multiple events, where one event only may have one author. I don't really know how I should make the queries for creating events and showing them.

For now I am creating an event with this query:

```
var newEvent = {
    date: req.param("date"),
    time: req.param("time"),
    other: req.param("other"),
    author: req.user
}

Event.create(newEvent).exec(function(err, model){
    console.log("New event created");
    console.log(model);
    return res.redirect("/account");
});
```

This is setting author to the users id and I guess that would be right. One question here is, do I have to update the collection in User-model as well? I guess not but I am not sure.

I am fetching some random events with this query:

```
Event.find().limit(5).exec(function(err, events) {
    return res.view({
        events: events
    });
});
```

And I want to get the users name in the ejs-template with this:

```
<% for( var i=0; i < events.length; i++) { %>
<li>
    <h3><%- events[i].author.name %></h3>
</li>
<% } %>
```

But this does not work. I think I am doing something wrong with the collection-field but I dont know what. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I added populateAll to the query which is doing the join thing.

```
Event.find().limit(5).populateAll().exec(function(err, events) {
    return res.view({
        events: events
    });
});
```